# Python maximum recursion depth reached error

Tags: python, recursion

So what I got here is a series of functions searching for the targeted value in a string.
(for example: find R in $&(*,.02468:<>@BDFHJLNPRTVXZ\^`bdfhj, H is found at index 18.)

But when the test for the function is executed for some characters it works fine but for some others(such as D or L) it gives me the ***"maximum recursion depth reached error"***.

Also for the characters in front such as $ in $&(*,.02468:<>@BDFHJLNPRTVXZ\^`bdfhj, the result is* "it cannot be found"*

As a newbie in python it is hard for me to see what is wrong in these functions, so what seems to be wrong here?

EDIT---------

Sorry for the confusion I meant **what seems to be wrong in the functions that are causing the maximum recursive depth error and how should I start to test these functions.**

```
def str_search( data, target, start, end ):

"""
str_search : String String NatNum NatNum -> NatNum or NoneType
Description:
Search for a target value in a sorted data string.
The search happens between the start and end indices inclusively.
This starts searching in the middle. If it finds the target, it is done.
Otherwise it decides whether to search the first half or the second half.
preconditions: the data string is in ascending alphanumeric order.
Parameters:
    data - a string
    target - the target value to find is a single character string e.g. 'Q'
    start - the starting index into the data
    end - the ending index into the data
Returns:
    index of target in data, if present; otherwise None.
"""

    if start == end:
        return None

    mid_index = ( start + end ) // 2
    mid_value = data[mid_index]

# debug statement prints the data.
#print( "Searching for", target, ":", data[start:mid_index], 
#    "*" + str( mid_value ) + "*", data[mid_index+1:end+1] )

    if target == mid_value:
        return mid_index
    elif target < mid_value:
        return str_search( data, target, start, mid_index-1 )
    else:
        return str_search( data, target, mid_index, end )

def find_target( data, target ):
"""
find_target : String String -> NatNum or NoneType
find_target returns the index of target in data or None if not found.
Parameters:
    data - a string
    target - the target value to find
Returns:
    The index of the target element in data, if present, or None.
"""

    return str_search( data, target, 0, len( data ) - 1 )

def makeString():
    """
    makeString : () -> String
    makeString returns a String
    """
    data = ""
    # append characters to make the string
    for num in range( 36, 108, 2 ):
        data += chr( num )
    return data

def main_search():
    """
    main_search : Void -> NoneType
    """

    data = makeString()
    print( "Number of elements: ", len( data ) )

    while True:
        print( "\nData: ", data )
        target = input( "Enter a character to find: " )

        if target == "":
            break
        else:
            index = find_target( data, target )
            print()
            if index != None:
                print( target, "found at index", index )
            else:
                print( target, "not found" )
# end while
```

Comment: Well, you obviously knew to insert some debugging print statements, so at what point does the debugging output differ from what you expected?

Comment: You're asking multiple questions here. Which one do you want an answer to? If it's the last one, just "what seems to be wrong", that's way too broad for StackOverflow. If it's about maximum recursion depth, that's easy (Python doesn't allow unbounded recursion, and doesn't do tail call elimination, so you can't use recursive algorithms that might have a depth approaching 1000), but almost certainly a duplicate. If it's about something else, tell us specifically what's wrong that you need to fix. The other stuff makes nice background detail, but we still need to know the actual problem.

Comment: Anyway, even without reading your code, I'm willing to be you've got an off-by-one error. That's really easy to do in a bisect algorithm. Look at the source to the stdlib's `bisect` module (linked from [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html); it's pretty easy to read and understand, so if you're trying to do the same thing, it should be easy to see (either by inspection or by printing out debug information) where your off-by-one is happening.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues in your **`str_search`** function.

1. Code below fails for `$` which is at the beginning. Your search eventually comes to `(start,end)=(0,0)` then `start == end` will be `True`, returning `None`

   ```
   if start == end:
       return None
   ```
2. Bigger problem is you enter into endless recursion loop in the code below when you search for 'D'. When you search for D, your start and end will be following `(0,35)`,`(0,16)`,`(8,16)`,`(12,16)`,`(14,16)`,`(15,16)`,`(15,16)`....**infinitely**!!!

   ```
   elif target < mid_value:
       return str_search( data, target, start, mid_index-1 )
   ```

I believe the fix for both 1 and 2 above can be done by handling situations where `end - start=1`.

**Remove lines below:**

```
if start == end:
    return None
```

**Replace with:**

```
if (end - start == 1):
    if target == data[end]:
        return end
    elif target == data[start]:
        return start
    else:
        return None
```

Quick sample way to test without having the you enter the input is:

```
def testSearch():
    data =  makeString()
    for target in data:
        index = find_target(data, target )
        print()
        if index != None:
            print( target, "found at index", index )
        else:
            print( target, "not found" )

testSearch()
```

However if you want thorough testing you would be better off using python unit-testing and use assertions. See the documentation here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html

Comment: Thanks! It did work! But now how would I test them if they work or not?

Comment: @Eric, You can write a function to loop through each character of the data and test if it succeeds. If you are asking how to write test cases for your code please look at python unit testing. I will update the answer with this info and please select it as answer if it answered your questions.

Answer (score 0):

This works without errors for the characters contained in the string:

```python
if target == mid_value:
    return mid_index
elif target == data[mid_index+1]:
    return mid_index+1
elif target < mid_value:
    return str_search( data, target, start, mid_index )
else:
    return str_search( data, target, mid_index, end )
```

Built-in python function:

```python
data = "something"
index_of_chr_in_string = data.find("m")
# or
print("something".find("t"))
```